# Platform specific import of dependency

Tags: react-native, dependency-management

I'm trying to do platform specific imports as I add support for web app as well. But I keep running into an import error for "ActionSheetIOS". I don't use this anywhere in my code, but this is a dependency for some number of my packages (react-native-map-link, react-native-share, etc). I've read that having .native.js and .js files for the package would fix an issue like this. How can I change this dependency and have my other packages installed by npm read from these edited files? Is there another easier fix to this?

Edit: This is the specific error I am getting if it helps.

```
./node_modules/react-native-map-link/src/utils.js
Attempted import error: 'ActionSheetIOS' is not exported from 'react-native'.
```

I've tried wrapping the code in the main files in Platform.OS selectors, so that's not the fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can create specific js file like `YourComponent.ios.js` and `YourComponent.android.js`.
then import "ActionSheetIOS" in `YourComponent.ios.js` file. Also check [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code#platform-specific-extensions).

Comment: Yes, I knew about this, but what happens when a package you want to use wants to import ActionSheetIOS? Just create a local copy of the package and add the extensions? At some point, you're having to create local copies of so many packages that it kind of renders npm useless.